# Python 3 /Tkinter: changing the font type, size, and color of a pre-defined label

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, label, frame

I'm using Tkinter with Python 3.6 (Windows 10).  I have a frame on a canvas, and the frame contains a label.  The label properties (i.e., font type, color, size) are to be selected by the user from drop-down menus during use of the GUI.  The initiation of the frame and its label are:

```
    self.defaultLeftStringValue                     = StringVar()       
    self.defaultRightStringValue                    = StringVar()
    self.leftFrame                                  = tf.TextInFrame(self.main_container, bg = 'white', 
                                                                     height = 128, width = 128)
    self.leftFrame.place( x = 10, y = 10)
    self.leftFrame.pack_propagate(False)
    self.leftLabel                                  = Label(self.leftFrame, textvariable=self.defaultLeftStringValue).pack()
```

Later, the user has selected the font type, size, and color with another method (doEnter:)

```
def doEnter(self):

    thisFontSize                                    = self.tkvarFontSize.get()
    thisFontColor                                   = self.tkvarFontFgColor.get()
    thisFontType                                    = self.tkvarFontType.get()
    self.leftFrame.config(bg=self.tkvarFontBgColor.get())
    self.rightFrame.config(bg=self.tkvarFontBgColor.get())
    font                                            = Font( family = thisFontType, size = thisFontSize )
    splitText                                       = self.text_entry.get()

    self.splitTextLeft                              = " "
    self.splitTextRight                             = " "
    if ";" in splitText:
        splitText                                   = splitText.split(";")
        self.splitTextLeft                          = splitText[0]
        self.splitTextRight                         = splitText[1]
        splitTextLeftLength                         = font.measure(self.splitTextLeft)
        splitTextRightLength                        = font.measure(self.splitTextRight)
        splitTextHeight                             = font.metrics("linespace")
        self.defaultLeftStringValue.set(self.splitTextLeft)
        self.defaultRightStringValue.set(self.splitTextRight)
```

All this works great; the entered text appears in the label of the left and right frames.  I'm even able to change the background color of the frame.  But, I cannot figure out how to change the label properties with thisFontSize (value = 10, type = class int), and thisFontColor (black, class str) and thisFontType (agencyfb, class str).  Hoping that someone can tell me how to change the properties of the text inserted into self.splitTextLeft, etc.

Comment: Have you tried `self.leftLabel.config(bg="black")` and `self.leftLabel.config(font=("agencyfb", 10))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line assigns `None` to `self.leftLabel`.

```
self.leftLabel = Label(self.leftFrame, textvariable=self.defaultLeftStringValue).pack()
```

You can't chain the geometry management methods and retain a reference to the widget. Do these steps separately. In your case you have no reference to the label instance so cannot set its properties later.

To illustrate:

```
x = tk.Label(root, text="ok").pack()
type(x)
<class 'NoneType'>
x = tk.Label(root, text="ok")
type(x)
<class 'tkinter.Label'>
```

Comment: I see.  I didn't realize that using the terminating widget method (.pack() in this case) would cause an irreversible loss of methods.  Thanks.

Comment: Just a comment for one reviewer: only having history with P3 and never with P2, is it reasonable to expect that a P3-only user would know that such a question should be entitled with P3?

Comment: @BenjaminLevy: I think the fact that OP (you actually) mentions P3 as his environment does not make for the need of the P3 tag. There is no issue in the question caused by the use of P3. This is a python tkinter question. As per "Use the more generic [python] tag if your question is not version-specific." So I think the title is perfectly well without mentioning it.